# Flutter Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter

I was trying to do a loading screen after pressing the button on the dialog.
After pressing the button on the dialog, the program will first pop the dialog, then show a WillPopScope object for 2 secs, after that it will pop the loading screen.
The code is as below:

```
onPressed: () async {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  loadingScreen(context);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

But it shows me the following error:

```
E/flutter (14960): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (14960): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (14960): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

After some research I believe this error caused by poping context which doesn't exist, so I tried to pop the dialog and the loading screen at the same time after the delay

```
onPressed: () async {
  loadingScreen(context);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  Navigator.pop(context);
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

Although it works but that's not exactly what I want, plus I am really confused why is that. Please can anyone explain to me what is happening and is there any way to solve it?

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> loadingScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () => Future.value(false), child: Text(''));
        });
  }

  dialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text('Show Loading Screen'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Okay'),
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                loadingScreen(context);
                await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: TextButton(
                child: Text('Show Dialog'),
                onPressed: () {
                  dialog(context);
                })));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main error is in the naming of the variables: When you call the dialog function from

```
Widget build(BuildContext context)...
```

You have the BuildContext as an argument for that function, and you use that context for the dialog. Let me rename your variables so that you can better understand:

```
dialog(BuildContext contextFromBuild) {  //this is the argument to the function
    return showDialog(
      context: contextFromBuild,
      builder: (BuildContext contextInsideDialog) { //new BuildContext inside the dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text('Show Loading Screen'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Okay'),
              onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pop(contextInsideDialog);
                loadingScreen(contextInsideDialog);
                await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
                Navigator.pop(contextInsideDialog);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

As you can see, you are popping the contextInsideDialog but then are trying to access it in:

```
loadingScreen(contextInsideDialog);
```

which causes the error, since you have already popped that context (contextInsideDialog). Simply fix it by renaming your variables.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. But it still gives me the same error until I modify your code into : loadingScreen(contextFromBuild); And the second pop : Navigator.pop(contextFromBuild); Anyway thanks a lot for the explanation, it's super helpful!

Comment: Thanks. It solved my issue after 2 hours.